# How to connect to Nexus and download jar file as dependency when building a docker image of a java project

Tags: java, docker, maven, nexus

1. I have a nexus docker container running on Port 8081, where I have deployed a JAR file.
2. I have a simple Java + Maven project, which downloads few dependencies from the Central and this one particular JAR from Nexus.
   I have a customized settings.xml to download

- Below is the snapshot:

(a) Dockerfile, which tries to builds an image

(b) Customized settings.xml

(c) pom.xml: distribution management section

[image]

[image]

[image]

When building (docker build -t= .), it downloads all dependencies from central, but fails to connect to the nexus and download.

[image]

*Note: Since everything is for learning purpose, everything is on my PC i.e localhost.

Update:

Below is the port mapping of docker containers.
[image]

Comment: Can you send the docker ps to verify nexus container port mapping?

Comment: The port mapping is same i.e 8081

Comment: Updated post to show port mapping.

Comment: I assume the problem is using `localhost` (which refers to the container address) instead of the address of the host machine where Nexus runs. You can try this if you use Docker Desktop: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker build` runs in a separate container where there is nothing under localhost:8081. Try to build using your host network:

```
docker build -t imagename --network host .
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked! Another query. If working in a company, and you will proxy, how will you define network in compose.xml and what is the build command you would use to build the docker image.

Comment: You can configure proxy settings on docker level: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

Comment: works perfectly for building an image ... thanks a lot